# How to test code that needs passed HTTPServletRequest

Tags: java, scala, servlets

I'm running some Scala code (with Java socialAuth library) that requires an HTTPServletRequest to be passed in as a param.

```
def myClass(prov: String, site: String, request: HttpServletRequest): {
    //some initial code here

    val session = request.getSession()
    session.setAttribute(/*some params*/)

    //code continues...

}
```

So the HttpServletRequest seems like a really cool way of storing session variables and passing a session between methods.  However, I'm not quite sure how to test this code, as I don't really understand what the HttpServletRequest interface *is*.

I've done a bit of research, but I was wondering if anyone could clarify for me.  [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) is an interface, which means it can't be instantiated on its own.  How, then is it used in code?

EDIT: as in, when a method takes an HttpServletRequest as a parameter, what implementing class is usually passed in?

---

FOLLOWUP: Based on the answers given, HttpServletRequest is implemented differently by different servers; Ireeder pointed out, for example, that Apache even has multiple implementations.  How, then, does code specify that the server needs to use its implementation? In other words, lets say I have test code that uses myClass:

```
def otherClass(){
    val site = "www.example.com"
    val provider = "twitter"
    val mockRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class)   //using https://code.google.com/p/mockito/.  (eclipse throws error..not too sure about syntax but throwing up this example quickly, so will edit later)

    myClass(provider, site, mockRequest)
    }
```

I assume this is OK for testing, as Mockito creates a mock object, but when otherClass() needs to be implemented on a server, how is its code adjusted?  (Sorry, I'm a bit new at this, so bear with me...) If `val mockRequest` needs to be implemented with whatever HttpServletRequest implementation is used by the server (Apache, Oracle, etc),  how does the user specify this in `otherClass`? Will something like this change:

```
//deleted line: --val mockRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class)
//changed line:  myClass(provider, site, mockRequest) to below:

myClass(provider, site, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

be interpreted and implemented correctly by the server?

Comment: It seems you are getting a little ahead of yourself if you are coding scala and don't know what an interface is. How does a trait work?

Comment: ... Classes implement interfaces. Interfaces specify a contract for the underlying implementation. Interfaces can't be instantiated, but classes *implementing* interfaces can. And no, tying code to the servlet spec isn't a really cool way of doing anything, because then you have to mock out stuff that's really only a thin layer between web clients and Code That Does Important Things.

Comment: I was wondering, more specifically, if either of you had experience with Java servlets and were familiar with what HttpServletRequest-implementing classes are most commonly used when testing programs that take an HttpServletRequest as a param

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Container implementers like Oracle or Apache extend the HttpServletRequest interface with their own implementations that actually do something.  You could do the same for your testing, or use something like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock it.

The only time you should be providing an implementation of an HttpServletRequest is at unit testing time, not when your code is running in a servlet container.  The container will pass you its own HttpServletRequest, and your code should not care about the exact implementation of that interface.  It should only use the methods provided by the HttpServletRequest interface so that it is independent of the container it is running in.

If you need to test the behavior of your code when it's running in servlet container, you can do manual testing, or use a testing framework that makes HTTP requests, like [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks Ireeder.  So, when one test the program over an Apache server, for example, does Apache use its own implementation of HttpServletRequest?

Comment: Perhaps a key point you're missing is that a framework will provide some sort of factory (or possibly injection) that abstractly bridges the gap between the interface (which you see) and the internal implementation which implements that interface (which the factor creates).  Your test framework will need it's own factory mechanism to create your test (mock) implementation.

Comment: @AlexSpangher - Yes, Apache Tomcat uses it's own implementation of HttpServletRequest. Actually several - here's one example: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html

Comment: thanks Ireeder.  As per my recent edit (FOLLOWUP), how does the user specify that the server must use its own implementation?

Comment: @AlexSpangher - I think you've got it reversed.  You cannot tell a server to use any implementation but its own.  I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: @Ireeder.  Thanks for your help thus far.  One more quick question. Where does the container pass its implementation?   Into any method that calls for an HttpServletRequest as a param?

Sorry, I don't think I'm expressing myself well. In other words, how should one structure a class like otherClass (in my FOLLOWUP) that uses myClass (and thus needs to pass in an HttpServletRequest)?  Should you simply include `HttpServletRequest request` as a param for otherClass as well, and will the container supply it?

Comment: @AlexSpangher Yes, if you implement one of the servlet-facing components in J2EE like HttpServlet which takes HttpServletRequest  and expose it in your web.xml, the container will pass its own implementation to your class.  You can continue to pass it down to your own classes, but it is *strongly* recommended to keep as much javax.servlet code as possible out of your own classes so they are reusable outside the context of a servlet container.

Answer (score 4):

Spring users can use the class `MockHttpServletRequest` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html))